# Collapse projects in Solution Explorer

Tags: visual-studio

How can I collapse / expand all projects in Solution Explore using keyboard?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Power Commands for VS2008 has a command to do this, plus lots of other neat tools

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/PowerCommands

You could also write a macro to do it, and assign it to a key combination

http://weblogs.asp.net/israelio/archive/2007/09/06/visual-studio-collapse-selected-node.aspx

Comment: See chad dienhart's answer. There is a button in VS 2013 to do this.

Comment: LOL -- I thought this was supposed to be hard.

Answer (score 89):

In **Visual Studio 2013** it is finally just part of solution explorer... with a "Collapse All" icon.
[image]

The right click option available with earlier versions of power tools in is not there but clicking the icon is easier anyway.

Comment: +1 because I've been looking for the 2013 equivalent of Power Commands and this was truly the only reason why.

Comment: Any idea what the keyboard binding is for that?  (not the keys, but what this is called in the Options | Keyboard dialog?

Comment: @PeterMcEvoy SolutionExplorer.CollapseAll (And Shift-Ctrl-Alt-L works well as the keyboard binding [to go with Ctrl-Alt-L to activate solution explorer])

Comment: Hmm - I can't see that command. Closest is a R# one (but I know you're a coderush guy) or a powercommands one - but that doesn't close sln folders.  The search continues....

Comment: @PeterMcEvoy Hmm, That's on 2015 community (I happen to have CR for Roslyn installed but that's a lot less invasive than CR was - and CR does not emit inject commands into that set - I guess it may be down to it not being exposed in the VS you have - maybe is in Update 2 [which I have on this box] ?). See [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35093599/11635) for confirmation of its existence (I never actually spotted the weakness cited in that post as I only ever look for it after I switch to it) :)

Comment: Hilarious -- thinking there HAD to be a difficult answer to this, I read Null's note above.  Said to myself 'oh really ...' right away skeptical that this icon would now be removed in 2019. :)  Nope, works great.

Answer (score 23):

The <kbd>*</kbd>, <kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>-</kbd> on the numeric pad controls do this:

- Open the solution explorer, select the folder to expand and press <kbd>*</kbd>.
- To collapse, press <kbd>-</kbd>.
- Then if you have collapsed some sub-folders, press <kbd>+</kbd> to return to your partially collapsed version.

Comment: * does a recursive expansion, +/- expand/collapse the selected folder/project. For some reason there appears to be no recursive collapse; some tools assign that function to '/' - but not VS (as far as I can tell)

Answer (score 6):

Press CTRL+ALT+L to focus on Solution Explorer. If it's not on the screen, or it's collapsed, this will focus on it.

Then press your left arrow key as many times as it takes to get to the solution, and with another left, it'll collapse the whole tree.

I jsut tested VS2008, and you can also press HOME, to get to the top of the tree.

If what you want, is the solution open, and all the project files closed, then ....

once you're home in the tree view, press down,left for each open project and|or open solution folder (if you have those).

The power tools that @Jason mentioned, might have a different solution, but this is how you can navigate the Solution Tree without any add-ins.

Comment: This solution is not practical if you have folders in your solution, because it collapses them.

Answer (score 0):

try this:
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/cb0ec47d-05a4-40a7-ba39-9a2da6492f1c/