# VS close all folders in solution explorer

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Just a general Q regarding features in VS.

I have downloaded the source code of a tutorial which contains a vast number of files and folders. For some reason unknown to myself whenever I open this particular project in VS all the folders will be open showing all the files in the project, in the solution explorer.

Instead of spending a few minutes minimizing all the folders in the project is there any general rule or option which will close all the folders when a project is opened/viewed from solution explorer.

Thanks

Comment: Check this link for a couple of options http://stackoverflow.com/questions/798039/collapse-projects-in-solution-explorer

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [PowerCommands for Visual Studio 2010](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e5f41ad9-4edc-4912-bca3-91147db95b99) or the [Productivity Power Tools for Visual Studio 2012](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3a96a4dc-ba9c-4589-92c5-640e07332afd).

Right-click in the Solution Explorer and choose *Collapse Projects*.